# selected item doesnt show on the spinner android

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have a spinner and I have added a custom style to spinner. Problem is when I select an item it doesnt show up on the spinner but when I use android spinner style it shows what I selected on the spinner. Is there any more coding to add to make it work? Otherwise everthing of the spinner works. I have written the app when an item is selected in spinner to show a text. These things work. But it doesnt show what I selected.

Here is my code

```
MyAdapter  dataAdapter3 = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner, list3);
spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
```

list 3 referes a list

```
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Here is the class for custom spinner style

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
      private List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();

      public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

      this.listString  = objects;
      }

      @Override
      public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
      }

      public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
       View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, parent, false);
       TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       label.setText(listString.get(position)); 

       return row;

      }
    }
```

please can anybody tell whether I have done any mistake here? 
This is how spinner is shows when I selected item
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried several days on this problem. Actually code is pretty ok. problem was in the spinner.xml file. I had added a large padding to textview. Therefore, though spinner works it is not visible the selected item on spinner. Point is I forget xml file. :D

Answer (score 0):

Modify the padding in the layout spinner.xml file to a lower value,
for ex:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="14sp" />
```