# Index out of bound exception

Tags: java, android, oop, spinner

I am trying to implement custom spinner style for the android spinner. There is a problem when I select an item in the spinner it doesnt show on the spinner (the selected item). I have several problems in my code.
Here is the log cat

```
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at com.xx.x.Page5SubActivity$MyAdapter.getCustomView(Page5SubActivity.java:487)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at com.xx.x.Page5SubActivity$MyAdapter.getView(Page5SubActivity.java:479)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:192)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:285)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-06 08:21:38.254: E/AndroidRuntime(733):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the class I use to customization of the spinner

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
      private List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();

      public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

      //listString  = objects;
      }

      @Override
      public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
      }

      public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
       View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, parent, false);
       TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       label.setText(listString.get(position)); 

       return row;

      }
    }
```

above error started when I comment this line  `//listString  = objects;` 
I commented it because  it has been initialized with super method.  `super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);` Can anybody explain me this? In OOP we use to super for initializing content with super class values. So why do I need to reinitialize that? Or can't we use super method for 2 parameters and initialize `//listString  = objects;` in the above class? I know I am lack of OOP. can anybody explain me?

Second problem is when I remove comments it starts to work. But it doesn't show up the item that I selected. I have written on item selected events. They works. what else I have to do to work this?

Comment: I can guarantee you that a private variable in your class has *not* been initialized with a call to `super()`. How would a parent class know anything about a private variable declared in a subclass?

Comment: yes I have declared `private List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();' private . Plz give me somtimes till project is built

Comment: I have the second problem still there. Why doesn't spinner is not showing the selected item on the spinner?

Comment: @Brian Roach, though I declared sub class variable as private . This works if I remove the comments before `//listString = objects;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listString` cannot be initialized by the super class. It is a member of the `MyAdapter` class and not the super class.

```
private List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
```

At the time of the `get` call `listString` is still empty, and thus the exception.

Comment: thanks and why doesn't it shows the selected item on the spinner?

Comment: @MenukaDevinda, is the problem still persisting even after fixing the above code for the exception?

Comment: Now it is ok after, I remove the comments spinner works but still there is my second problem

Comment: @MenukaDevinda I am not really sure, perhaps it merits a different question?

Comment: like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171030/selected-item-doesnt-show-on-the-spinner-android ..

Comment: Actually I added the problem, there is no answers for that from yesterday that's why I added that question to this one. anyway thanks for your help